# How To Get Ionic 4 To Work On Android 5.1

Tags: android, ionic-framework, android-5.0-lollipop, ionic4

I currently just created an Ionic 4 application and when i test on my android 5.1 device nothing shows, i go to google to find out what the issue could be and it turns out ionic 4 has a problem working on android 5.1 and lower devices. Is there anyway to get it to run on at least android 5.1 ?

Comment: Are you using cordova or capacitor?

Comment: I'm using cordova

Answer (score 2):

It appears that Ionic has a closed issue on Github for this that states that Android 5 is not entirely supported:

https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/15438

One of the Ionic team members states:

"We are aware of this issue and have been working to fix it for some time. The main issue here is that there seems to be a constant stream of things that need to either be polyfill or reworked in order to support older Android. And to add to this, the android emulator is not always the best test ground

As the older android emulators are not connected to google play, they do not receive updates to the browser, meaning that though a real android 5 device might have chrome 70, the emulator is stuck on chrome 37 (~1% of the global market), which is a drastically different environment.

While we are making fixes internally in both stencil and ionic/(core,angular), devs can enable Angular Polyfills to fix some older features.

For most cases though, people will not be seeing "older" webviews that devs are getting in the Android emulator. They will be getting new chrome (70+) and all the latest web features.

We will we continuing to address this issue and make sure things work as expected."